# jqgrid - validation of form data at entry time (or how do I get onblur events to bubble up?)

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to do validation of entries via Ajax. I am validating if the information entered is valid Perl regexp before the user submits the data. Is there a way to use the onblur() event from the individual input field to do the validation?

Reading the docs it seems that I can override each event globally, but I want to be able to perform different checks for each input field. I also know there is the beforeSubmit() event, but that is generated too late for what I want to do.

I am using jqgrid 4.1.2.

Any help would be appreciated.

J